# Java. String contents to create an object's instance

Tags: java, reflection

I know this is part of *java.lang.reflect.** but I wasn't able to find any suggestions to point me how to tackle this.

I want to use the contents of a string to create and instance of an object that has the name of what the string stores.

Eg.
    `String[] carName = {"volvo","vw","bmw"};`
    `car carName[0];`
    `car carName[1];`
    `car carName[2];`

I've stumbled upon this snippet, which looks promising:
   `Car car = (Car) Class.forName("Volvo").newInstance();`
It throws back: `Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException`

edit: *Sorry for not being clear enough, I'm not in any way a professional. No, I don't have a class called Volvo. I'm actually trying to define one generic class (car) and then initialize instances of it via strings.*

Comment: That's a compilation error. This is not a reflection question, this is a question about getting java to compile.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this using reflection like this? If it's an exercise fair enough. Otherwise though, I personally wouldn't use it. By using Class.forName() you're forcing your users to input the exact name of the class (case sensitive, no extra characters or anything else, and it can never contain spaces.) I'd at least have a map of string=>class name somewhere that you maintain, that way you can still instantiate objects reflectively but the name to get to that class becomes much more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to either `catch` the `ClassNotFoundException`, or declare it to be thrown from your method
2. You need to specify the fully-qualified name of your class. If the class is in packaged as `foo.cars.Volvo`, then use that as its name.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if the class you reference isn't on the classpath. Make sure you reference the full package, e.g.

```
com.example.Volvo
```

when using `Class.forName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class called `Volvo` which extends `Car`?

`Class.forName` requires a fullly qualified classname, so it might be `org.example.Volvo` or whatever you've named your class.

Or are you trying to create a new car object that has a value of carName?

**Edit:**

Then what you're looking for is probably more like (i didn't try to compile this, so...)

```
string[] names = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen" };
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

for(string name : cars)
{
    // presuming you have a class Car with a constructor that takes a string
    cars.Add(new Car(name));
}
```

if you already know you have a class called car, you don't need to mess with any of the reflection stuff to create one.

Comment: No, I don't have a class called Volvo. I'm actually trying to define one generic class (car) and then initialize instances of it via strings.